# How to not load images for smaller screen

Tags: javascript, image, image-size

I have come across numerous solutions from different articles but which one would put the least strain on the CPU?
There is 
  https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/
  https://github.com/teleject/hisrc
but which one is recommended and has the best compatibility with browsers?

Comment: You could use js to detect the size and set the `src` is the screen size is big enough

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @teemu your just hiding them, they still get loaded in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you plan on doing. If you don't want elements to have a background image if the screen size is too small then you could use media queries e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body{
            background-image: none;
        }
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 301px) {
    body{
            background-image: url("/url/to/image.jpeg");
        }
    }
}
```

But if you want to control whether a certain image tag's source is loaded you could do this:

```
if(screen.width > 300) image.src = "/url/to/image.jpeg";
```

On the other hand, you could just hide the image tag using the same media queries

Answer (score 0):

Use the css @media to detect the screen width to control whether load or not load image.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    img {
        display: none;
    };
}
```

or use javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (screen.width <= 400px) {
        $("img").css('display', 'none');
    }
  }
);
```